# I want to create a special query with GraphiQL and only get certain fields - but i got all fields

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have the following simple code in GraphiQL:

```
{
 users {    
   first_Name
   last_Name
 }
}
```

I have my own endpoint, which also provides data.
The query does not give me the desired result, but always returns all fields. I also don't see the data object. But i also got no error code.

[image]

Comment: you should check the resolver for the implementation -

Comment: As @DenisTsoi said on your backend check resolver for getUserbyId you must be returning all fields there

Comment: There's really not enough information here to help you debug your issue. Can you provide a repo link or a reproducible example using CodeSandbox?

Comment: query is good, your server is not graphql specs compliant